# PHPMailer sending to multiple address separated by a ,

Tags: php, email

I am using PHPMailer to send emails, i use this to add the email address to send to:

```
$email->AddAddress($result["emailto"]);
```

my email addresses are coming from a database, it works fine but if the emailto column in my database looks like:

```
email1@domain.com,email2@domain.com
```

i get an error saying *You must provide at least one recipient email address.*

how can i get round this to be able to send to multiple addresses?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should explode it and then add the emails.

```
$addresses = explode(',', $result["emailto"]);
foreach ($addresses as $address) {
    $email->AddAddress($address);
}
```

Comment: I did but it not worked with comma separated emails.

Answer (score 2):

```
//Explode by comma so that we get an array of emails.
$emailsExploded = explode(",", $result["emailto"]);

//If the array isn't empty, loop through
if(!empty($emailsExploded)){
    foreach($emailsExploded as $emailAddress){
        $email->AddAddress(trim($emailAddress));
    }
} else{
    //This should not be the case.
    throw new Exception('No emails found!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do a explode on the , character and then do a foreach trough the array to add adresses.

```
$addresses = explode(',',$result["emailto"]);
foreach ( $addresses as $address ){
    $email->AddAddress($address);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have to do multiple calls to `AddAddress` or use a ; instead of a ,

Try doing this:

```
$email_array = explode(',', $result['emailto']);
for($i = 0; $i < count($email_array); $i++) {
    $email->AddAddress($email_array[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with an array, something like this :

```
$array = explode(",",$result["emailto"]);
$nb = count($array);
for ($i=0;$i<$nb;$i++) {
    $email->AddAddress($array[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `foreach (explode($result["emailto"], ',') as $email) {$email->AddAddress($email);}`